# Prove that $g(x)=\frac{x^2}{\sin^2 x}\, (1+\cos x)$ is an increasing function for $x\in[0,\pi/2]$.

Tags: calculus, functions

Prove that function
$$g(x)=\frac{x^2}{\sin^2 x}\, (1+\cos x)$$
is an increasing function for $x\in[0,\pi/2]$. I tried to calculate $g'(x)$ but is very difficult to determine its sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$g(x)=\frac{x^2(1+\cos x)}{\sin^2x}\cdot\frac{1-\cos x}{1-\cos x}=\frac{x^2}{1-\cos x}$$
So,
$$g'(x)=\frac{2x(1-\cos x)-x^2\sin x}{(1-\cos x)^2}=\frac{x}{(1-\cos x)^2}(2-2\cos x-x\sin x)$$
Let $h(x):=2-2\cos x-x\sin x$. Then,
$$h'(x)=\sin x-x\cos x,\qquad h''(x)=x\sin x.$$

Now for $0\le x\le \pi/2$, we have that $h''(x)\gt 0$, and so $h'(x)$ is increasing with $h'(0)=0$. So, since $h'(x)\gt 0$ for $0\le x\le \pi/2$, we have that $h(x)$ is increasing with $h(0)=0$, and so, $h(x)\gt 0\Rightarrow g'(x)\gt 0$ leads that $g(x)$ is increasing.

Answer (score 3):

At x=0, assume that the function value is 2 (else it is not defined).
Hint: $1+\cos(x) = 2\cos^2(x/2)$ and $\sin(x) = 2\sin(x/2)cos(x/2)$. Then it becomes
$$g(x) = \frac{x^2}{2\sin^2(x/2)}$$
As g(x) is non-negative, you can now take log on both sides and differentiate. If you need more help, let me know in comments.